# Twilio video codec is not supported H264

Tags: android, sdk, twilio, call, h.264

We are using twilio video sdk in our android app, on some devices, we are getting TwilioException in onVideoTrackSubscriptionFailed callback, can anyone suggest some solution to this ,

> error No supported codec video/H264/90000 is not supported. Supported
>   codecs: [video/VP8/90000/1,fmtps:[]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented here:

[Twilio Video SDKs: Supported codecs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/managing-codecs#twilio-video-sdks-supported-codecs)

How about VP8?